# QueryBuilder Invalid PathExpression. Must be a StateFieldPathExpression

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, doctrine, query-builder

Trying to fetch all `supplierUsers` where the id is DISTINCT and hydrate the results.

The SQL query to get all the results would be the following

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT supplier_user_id FROM job_item_quote
```

The Query builder to fetch the above.

```php
$qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('a')
        ->select('a.supplierUser')
        ->distinct(true);
$result = $qb->getQuery()->getResult();
```

Outputted `getQuery()`. Which is exactly what I'm looking for.

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT a.supplierUser FROM Project\Entities\JobItemQuote a
```

The error thrown when trying to fetch distinct users

```
[Semantical Error] line 0, col 18 near 'supplierUser,': Error: Invalid PathExpression. Must be a StateFieldPathExpression.
```

I've tried adding joins in for `supplierUser` in hopes it would fix. Same error thrown.

JobItemQuote Entity

```php
/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="Project\Repositories\JobItemQuote\JobItemQuoteRepository")
 * @ORM\Table(name="job_item_quote")
 */
class JobItemQuote extends BaseEntity
{
    public static $joins = [
        'supplierUser' => SupplierUser::class,
        'jobItem' => JobItem::class
    ];
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @var int
     */
    protected $id; // thekey

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="JobItem", inversedBy="quotes")
     * @var JobItem
     */
    protected $jobItem;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="SupplierUser")
     * @var SupplierUser
     */
    protected $supplierUser;

    
    ....

}
```

SupplierUser Entity

```php
/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="Project\Repositories\SupplierUser\SupplierUserRepository")
 * @ORM\Table(name="supplier_user")
 */


class SupplierUser extends User {

    public static $joins = [
        'supplier' => Supplier::class,
        'supplierGroup' => SupplierGroup::class
    ];

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="Supplier", inversedBy="supplierUser", cascade={"persist"})
     * @var Supplier
     */
    protected $supplier;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="SupplierGroup")
     * @var Group
     */
    protected $supplierGroup;

    ....
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your need is to retrieve the list of `supplierUsers` associated with `JobItemQuote`, so you should make the query in `JobItemQuoteRepository` making a `join` with `supplierUsers`, you find bellow the example :

```
$qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('jiq')
          ->select('su')
          ->join(SupplierUser::class, 'su', Join::With, 'su.id = jiq.supplierUser')
          ->distinct(true)
      ;

$result = $qb->getQuery()->getResult();
```

By this query you will have the list of SupplierUser (distinctly) assoiated to JobsItemQuote.

Comment: Thanks! had to make a minor change `Join::With` had to become `'with'` and the namespacing applied to the class, then it worked perfectly. Seemed that doctrine wasn't pulling the supplierUser as the entity as expected, had to be manually defined in the join.